# Render HTML with MVC ViewBag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Is there a way to render HTML tags from a ViewBag? I am pulling article content out of a database, but the HTML tags included in the article aren't rendered.

For example:

```
ViewBag.ArticleContent = "Machine <strong>Language</strong> Content";
```

The tag doesn't render, it just shows up as text. This is a static string, but I get the same issue when I assign to ViewBag.ArticleContent from the database.

Comment: This behavior is by-design in the Razor view-engine as a means of preventing XSS attacks. You must explicitly call `Html.Raw` to render text directly to the output stream without HTML-encoding.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get it working. I have posted my solution as well, in case it can help someone else.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. This appears to be working:

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.ArticleContent)
```